# Javascript timer countdown in Mozilla and IE - works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, countdown

The Javascript below is used to format a range of timers for my php game. When a user submits an option it then resets the timer saying "Ready" to count down 1 minute based on the time logged when the user submitted against the current time. When the timer reaches '0' it then resets to default of "Ready". It's working perfect with CHrome however Firefox and IE it only displays Ready but will not update the timer and begin counting down. Any help is deeply appreciated.

```
var d = new Date();

var tarray = new Array();

function loadTimers()
{
    var timersrow = g('timersrow');
    var html = '';
    var list = tinfo.split('|');
    var i;
    var cell
    for ( i=0; i<list.length; i++ ) {
        data = list[i].split(',');

        cell = ce('td');
        cell.innerHTML = data[0];
        timersrow.appendChild(cell);

        //html += '<td id="tcell' + data[0] + '">' + data[0] + '</td>';
        tarray[tarray.length] = new objTimer(data[0], data[1], cell);
    }
    //timersrow.innerHTML = html;

    updateTimers();
}

function updateTimers() {
    var i;
    for ( i=0; i<tarray.length; i++ ) {
        tarray[i].update(); 
    }
    setTimeout('updateTimers();', 250);
}

function objTimer(label, time, cell)
{
    this.label = label;
    this.time = Date.parse(time);
    this.cell = cell;

    function update() 
    {
        var t = new Date();
        var val = this.time - t.getTime();
        if ( val > 0 ) {
            this.cell.innerHTML = 'Next ' + this.label + ': ' +  formatSeconds(val);
        } else {
            this.cell.innerHTML = 'Next ' + this.label + ': Ready';
        }
    }
    this.update = update;
}

function formatSeconds(seconds) 
{   
    var h = 0, m = 0,
    seconds = parseInt(seconds / 1000);
    if (seconds > 60 * 60 ) {
        h = parseInt(seconds / (60 * 60));
        seconds -= h * 60 * 60;
    }
    if ( h < 10 ) {
        h = '0' + h;    
    }
    if ( seconds > 60 ) {
        m = parseInt(seconds / 60);
        seconds -= m * 60;
    }
    if ( m < 10 ) {
        m = '0' + m;    
    }
    if ( seconds < 10 ) {
        seconds = '0' + seconds;    
    }
    return h + ':' + m + ':' + seconds;
}

loadTimers();
```

Comment: We really like jsfiddle / codepen :)

Comment: I agree but there a many pages and php vars etc to make this script work. Im hoping someone can see an error in my javascript that may be a reason why firefox and ie aren't liking it. Unless its a problem with my date formats

Comment: just to exclude probably no-errors: declare your `function`s before you use them, and add the `radix`-parameter to your `parseInt`-calls like that `parseInt(seconds / 60, 10)`.. but that would probably not solve the issue

Comment: In that case, you should check the console. There are debugging options to set breakpoints in JS. Perhaps it has to do with some method calls. For example, `appendChild` didnt work in older versions (FF & IE now do, but as an example..) Perhaps your variables have names of default keywords, you know? Maybe someone else does see it right away..

Comment: btw: in your function `formatSeconds()` you basically do sth. like that: `seconds = parseInt(parseInt(seconds/1000) / (60 * 60)) * 60 * 60;`... 2 things migth be superfluous

Comment: it seems like as if you use parseInt() to round, better use `Math.round(number)` or `Math.floor(number)` to do so, because if i'm right, the first if-cascade will always result in `seconds === 0`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help. I have resolved the issue as I believe having functions called before they are defined was one of the key issues and changing the rounding system to math.floor instead of parseInt.

Also silly me - Var cell had no ';' which may have been the biggest reason.